# java создание демон-процесса

Tags: java

Есть какой-либо способ создать демон-процесс на windows, который будет работать в фоновом режиме, используя какую-либо библиотеку или стандартные средства?

Comment: в многопоточности можно создать поток демон.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря что считать демон-процессом, работающим в фоновом режиме. Самое простое - запустить консольное приложение с помощью javaw.

Answer (score 1):

Можно приложение обернуть врапером в windows сервис, и оно будет работать в фоне.